# Complete location bar URL with https if the scheme is omitted

Tags: firefox, https, address-bar

HTTP clients such as web browsers have been adding the `http:` scheme to URLs when the user enters `example.com` without being very specific. This will result in an request to `http://example.com/`.

Is it possible to make Firefox assume `https:` instead such that `example.com` gets written as `https://example.com/`? When explicitly asking for `http://example.com/`, it should not be rewritten though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the HTTPS by default addon: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/https-by-default

If a scheme ("http:") is not given, the addon assumes that you want to navigate to https version of the site. If the site cannot be reached over https, Firefox's usual error page is displayed. If the site does not support https, edit the URL in the location bar, delete the "s" in https and try again.

<sub>(disclosure: I developed this addon, its source code is available at https://github.com/Rob--W/https-by-default)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you need EFF's [HTTPS Everywhere](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/https-everywhere/) plugin. Or if you are running a server, you could serve a `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000` header over HTTPS. That would force browsers to use HTTPS for that server for the next year.

Comment: HTTPS Everywhere seems to work with a whitelist, but it does not avoid having me to type `https://` for new domains. I have HSTS enabled for my own domains, but it does not help with other sites. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Comment: Time to recompile Firefox then. Or maybe see if the source for HTTPS Everywhere is available. Should be easy to change the whitelist lookup you mention with an "if (true)". Use the source Luke!